Can I use the "by" keyword to implement two interfaces with the same delegate?
I am trying to implement two interfaces, using the same delegate for both. So if I want to implement these interfaces:
interface A {
    fun foo()
}

interface B {
    fun bar()
}


with a delegate from this class

class C: A, B {
    override fun foo() {
        println("foo!")
    }

    override fun bar() {
        println("bar!")
    }
}

to do it using the by keyword, I could try something like this
class D: A by C(), B by C()


but this requires creating two instances of C, which may not be desirable.
Or I could try
class D(c: C = C()): A by c, B by c


which requires changing the constructor. This may also not be desirable.
Is there some way to do this efficiently, or do I have to go with boilerplate and implement A and B in the class body?

I would concur that creating two different C instances sounds bad, so the only way to go is to use your second approach.
If you do not want to expose the constructor with the C parameter you can make that private and use a secondary, parameterless constructor that is public. This way the delegate shenanigans with C are strictly internal and not visible from the outside:
class D private constructor(c: C) : A by c, B by c {
    constructor() : this(C())
}


Didn't think about the secondary constructor, thanks. Exactly why I asked this.

The constructor approach would be what you have to do here. You are probably better off just implementing the delegation internally, but if you wanted to keep the same construction signature while delegating, you could use a pseudoconstructor approach:
class D private constructor(private val c: C = C()) : A by c, B by c {
  companion object {
    operator fun invoke() = D()
  }
}

External users of the class would still create an instance via D() (they would not see the D(C) constructor since it is private).
